# Embedding the view of a url inside the header of another view

Tags: drupal, highcharts, drupal-views

Currently, I have a dynamically created custom pie chart located at mywebsite.com/customchart that is created through a module I made using Highcharts.

I have view, that is listed in the views module shown in mywebsite.com/admin/structure/views/view/ which I would like to embed the custom chart into but I cannot find it through **Add Header>Global: View area**.

How exactly would one be able to achieve this?   Programatically?  How?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically.

First you have to find out what template file is used for rendering the header. Easiest way: go editing your view, select proper display and then unfold "Advanced" options block on the right column and click "Theme: information". Here you can see what templates files are used (assuming you are using Drupal 7). The used ones are in **bold**. You can collect actual template code there so you don't have to find template file at all if you want to override it. And you can see file naming suggestions, so there you have everything you need to override template file.

If your theme is not overriding standard templates then you should do that - it's not good idea to change directly templates provided by Views module.

So, the first part would be finding out where would you like to embed the view, at what template and at what position. Second part is using function `views_embed_view()` for doing that:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x

As you can see there, first parameter is machine name of the view, second of display and then you can pass parameters if your view accepts them. So call that function from proper place and you'll have your view embedded.

Also, there is display type "embed" which you can use for embedding views like this. It will provide those "edit view" links when you hover your view content while logged in as admin...